# How to Copy Data (Rows) of Sql Server into MySql in Real-time Using Java Code?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, sql-server

I have one GPS tracker device whose data are inserted into Sql Server by Default but problem is I want to create Database in MySql ..

So give suggesttion about how to copy or migrate Data of Sqlserver into MySql in Real time-.

Comment: so you want to have two databases running at the same time? that doesnt sound very useful. Try to get the device to work with mysql or try to do everything else you want to do with the sql server. Not sure if its possible to do replication from sql to mysql in realtime, but i think even if so - that is not a nice solution and an additional part where problems can occure.

Comment: yes i have to make Code like Logger that accept Data into Sql server and also it enter into Mysql . But my device send data into sql server by default

Comment: You said "by Default" twice. This sounds like this can be changed. If not why dont you use the sql server if it has to be there anyway? If you are really going to have both, SQL Server has alot of replication features, but I dont know if mysql can work with that.

Answer (score 0):

You can schedule a batch job that will read the data from SQL Server using JDBC (or hibernate) and insert it to MySQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

I'm developing the solution that you're asking for.
I've added to my build path in eclipse two library:

mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin.jar (for MySQL)
http://www.mysql.it/downloads/connector/j/

jtds-1.3.0.jar (for MSSQL) 
http://jtds.sourceforge.net/

If you use Eclipse it's a good idea download SQL Explorer and try the connection under that.
The string that you must use for the connections are:

```
 String url="jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://IP-SERVER:1433/DB";
 String url2="jdbc:mysql://IP-SERVER:3306/DB";
```

Before than you must pay attention that MySQL and MSSQL accept external connection if you aren't under localhost.
For MySQL you must modify in the configuration file the parameter bind that have 127.0.0.1 as default value, change it in 0.0.0.0 (not secure) or with a list of allowed IP.
For MSSQL you must be sure that TCP-IP it's enabled and that the defaults ports are 1433.

In java you can easily open two different connection and copy records between different DB.
It's a good idea if the data are big use the PreparedStatement that improve the performance if you, for example, need to copy from MSSQL local to MySQL remote.
Here a piece of code without exception handler that I've removed for make a message more short.

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

java.sql.Statement s;
java.sql.ResultSet rs;
java.sql.Statement s2;
java.sql.ResultSet rs2;
java.sql.PreparedStatement psmtMySQL;

con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, id, pass);
con2 = DriverManager.getConnection(url2, id2, pass2);

if(con!=null && con2!=null){
    try{
s = con.createStatement();
rs = s.executeQuery(sql);        

sql ="INSERT INTO TABLE (FIELD1, FIELD2, FIELD3) " + "VALUES (?,?,?);"; 

con2.setAutoCommit(false);
psmtMySQL = con2.prepareStatement(sql);        
con2.setAutoCommit(true);
while( rs.next() ){
    try {             
        psmtMySQL.setLong(1, rs.getLong("Field1"));
        psmtMySQL.setLong(2, rs.getLong("Field2"));
        psmtMySQL.setString(3, rs.getString("Field3"));
        psmtMySQL.addBatch()    ;
    } catch (SQLException sqle){         
        sqle.printStackTrace();               
    }
}
psmtMySQL.executeBatch();
con2.setAutoCommit(true);
psmtMySQL.close();
rs2.close();
s2.close();
conn2.close();
rs.close();
s.close();
conn.close();
```